# How to do substitution of variable with power in Mathematica?

Tags: replacement

I want to replace $x^{i+1}$ with $z_i$.

EDIT:
I have some latex equations, and wish to import them to MMa.

How to replace x_i (NOT $x_i$) with $x[i]$

But it seems the underscore "_" has a special meaning (function), can we do such substitution in MMa?

**EDIT2:**

For example, I want to convert the following two latex equations:

```
        `{la_3^2=0, la_1la_3-6la_3ps=0}`
```

into

```
        `{la[3]^2==0, la[1]*la[3]-6*la[3]*ps==0}`
```

so that I could apply Simplify or Solve to these equations later.

Great thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't use `x_i` see `Blank` and see `FullForm[x_i]`. See also `BlankSequence`, `BlankNullSequence`. These characters have very special meanings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To put in the offset by `1` that was desired in the question, one could do this:

```
x^(i+1) /. x^exponent_ :> Subscript[z, exponent - 1]
```

The rule works independently of whether `i` is an integer or not. I didn't take care of the special case `i=0`, but that would be doable just like in Artes' answer.

The difference in my answer is that I use `RuleDelayed` (`:>`) which allows me to do the subtraction of `1` on the *right-hand* side of the rule., instead of looking for the `+1` in the pattern on the left-hand side (which could equally be a valid approach).

**Edit**

If your actual application is to import a $\LaTeX$ string, then the usual approach would be something like this:

```
latexString = "x_i + x^{i+1}";
ToExpression[latexString, TeXForm]
```

> $x_i + x^{i+1}$

The output is of course an expression that *no longer contains* the `Blank` symbol `_`. So your substitution would miss the target if it were now to look for a `_`. Instead, it has to look for the translated expression pattern involving `Subscript` $x_i$.

The general rule when you're not sure what pattern to look for in performing  substitutions on Mathematica expressions is: take an example expression, and wrap it in `InputForm[expression]` to see how it is represented internally. For more complicated cases, you'll have to inspect `FullForm[expression]`.

On the other hand, when importing $\LaTeX$ one can also run into a different kind of trouble: the input may not correspond to a valid expression, which will cause an error when doing `ToExpression`. In such cases it's sometimes necessary to do `StringReplace`.

That would also be something you could do in your example.But I'm not sure if that's what you want, so I'll leave it out for now.

**Edit 2**

I Mathematica, $\LaTeX$ code has to be put into strings by surrounding it with quotation marks. Otherwise you're asking for trouble (syntax errors).

When $\LaTeX$ code is inside a string, you furthermore have to escape the backslash character so that `\sin` becomes `\\sin` etc. Even with these precautions, it isn't guaranteed that Mathematica will understand your $\LaTeX$ code, as I mention on [this web page](http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/computernotes/Mathematica/EquationEditing.html).

One useful trick that you can always try, though, is to take an example Mathematica expression that you would like to produce from $\LaTeX$, and find out what the correct $\LaTeX$ source for it would be by doing this:

```
mmaCode = {la[3]^2==0, la[1]*la[3]-6*la[3]*ps==0}
ToString[TeXForm[mmaCode]]
```

This will tell you what the *input* string should be, to get the expression in `mmaCode`.

Now you can *copy* the output of this command, and when you paste it again it will have the escaped backslashes appear automatically.

This is what I'm doing now, by pasting the last result back into a `ToExpression`:

```
ToExpression[
  "\\left\\{\\text{la}(3)^2=0,\\text{la}(1) 
    \\text{la}(3)-6 \\text{la}(3) \\text{ps}=0\\right\\}", 
 TeXForm
]

(* ==> {9 la == 0, -6 ps la[3] + la[1] la[3] == 0} *)
```

Notice how equals signs are treated differently in $\LaTeX$ and Mathematica (`=` versus `==`), and how variable names with more than one character **have to** be wrapped in `\text` in order to be correctly recognized as a single symbol in Mathematica. If you don't do that, every character is interpreted as a separate variable name.

So what does this mean for your example *input*? First we have to write it in quotation marks because of what I just said, and then we have to *escape* the curly brackets as you see in the previous output of `TeXForm`. Lastly, the variable names have to be wrapped in `\\text`:

```
inputString = 
 "\\{\\text{la}_3^2=0, \\text{la}_1\\text{la}_3-6\\text{la}_3\\text{ps}=0\\}"
```

With this, you can finish the conversion to Mathematica:

```
mmaCode2 = ToExpression[inputString, TeXForm]
```

On the result, we can now do the pattern replacements that started this post.

```
mmaCode2 /. Subscript[la, i_] -> la[i]

(* ==> {la[3]^2 == 0, -6 ps la[3] + la[1] la[3] == 0} *)
```

Comment: cool. I just edited my original post with more details. It seems when I use ToExpression["la_1la_2"], MMa will treat `l` and `a_i` as separate variables, but I want to treat `la` as one variable. Any idea?

Comment: I've added a discussion of this to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
x^3 + 3 x^2 - 5 x /. {x^(i_Integer) -> Subscript[z, i], x -> Subscript[z, 1]}
```

[image]

As rcollyer suggested in the comment it can be shortened to

```
x^3 + 3 x^2 - 5 x /. x^(i_Integer: 1) :> Subscript[z, i]
```

Comment: I prefer `RuleDelayed` for this, having the `HoldRest` attribute. Also, it can be shortened to `x^(i_Integer:1):> Subscript[z,i]`.

Comment: @rcollyer  Thanks for your suggestion.